# "Your flagging history" is broken when a user has only raised helpful spam flags

Tags: bug, flags

Take a look at this:

[image: My flagging history on Webmasters.SE]

The "Your flagging history" summary is **gone**! On a site where I have more flags...

[image: My flagging history on Stack Overflow]

This is fine. It seems that whenever the first section has no data to show, nothing shows.

Comment: Confirmed on some of my accounts that were created just to fight spam on a specific site.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, should I write a userscript that hides the heading when the body is missing? :-D

Comment: @JanDvorak That could be reasonable. I would pull data from the current page though and use `n+ posts marked as spam`, etc.